# Add two arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays and I want to add it to make a combined one.

```
$first = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [countrySelected] => 3
            [stateSelected] => 176
            [citySelected] => 551
        )

)
$second = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [countrySelected] => 3
            [stateSelected] => N/A
            [citySelected] => N/A
        )

)
```

Now I want to make them a combined one:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [countrySelected] => 3
            [stateSelected] => 176
            [citySelected] => 551
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [countrySelected] => 3
            [stateSelected] => N/A
            [citySelected] => N/A
        )
)
```

I tried it with array_merge but it combines them in one but I need two elements like [0], [1] as above.

Comment: There is no difference between the arrays. What are you trying to do?

Comment: can u please put ur php code

Comment: @Andreas question updated.

Comment: @KishanOza question updated.

Comment: How did you use `array_merge`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are, simply use `array_map` like below:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
    array(
            "countrySelected" => 3,
            "stateSelected" => 176,
            "citySelected" => 551
        )

);
$array2 = array(
    array(
            "countrySelected" => 3,
            "stateSelected" => "N/A",
            "citySelected" => "N/A",
        )

);

array_map(function($arr) use(&$array1){
    $array1[] =  $arr;
}, $array2);

print_r($array1);
```

check output here https://paiza.io/projects/lJSL9E0IKJ1VF5IreDNmvA

Answer (score 3):

You can use array_merge_recursive:

```
$arr1 = array(
        array(
                "countrySelected" => 3,
                "stateSelected" => 176,
                "citySelected" => 551
        )
);

$arr2 = array(
        array(
            "countrySelected" => 3,
            "stateSelected" => Null,
            "citySelected" => Null
        )
);

$arr3 = array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2);
print_r($arr3);

Result:
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [countrySelected] => 3
        [stateSelected] => 176
        [citySelected] => 551
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [countrySelected] => 3
        [stateSelected] =>
        [citySelected] =>
    )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

have you used **array_push** ?
it could be something like:

```
array_push($Array2,$Array1[0]);
```

first parameter is the destination, the second is the element to insert.

array_push() insert it on the last field in array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrayone = array(WHATEVER VALUES ARE IN THIS ARRAY);
$arraytwo = array(WHATEVER VALUES ARE IN THIS ARRAY));
```

then combine the arrays like following

```
$arraythree = array($arrayone, $arraytwo);

var_dump($arraythree);
```

Comment: Sorry, I did. I am new here so please excuse the error, it wont happen again!

Comment: It created additional key as: [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array

Answer (score 0):

My approach -

Case 1 - 
If you don't know how many keys will be present

```
$mergedArray = [];
foreach($array1 as $key=>$value)
{         $mergedArray[] = $value;    } //similarly for array 2
```

Case 2 - If there is only a single key present in the associative array

```
$mergedArray = [];
$mergedArray[] = $array1[0];
$mergedArray[] = $array2[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array_merge_recursive` check simple example [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_array_merge_recursive)

```
<?php
    $a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green");
    $a2=array("c"=>"blue","b"=>"yellow");
    print_r(array_merge_recursive($a1,$a2));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with below code

```
$arr1=array('countrySelected'=>3,'stateSelected'=>176,'citySelected'=>551);
$arr2=array('countrySelected'=>3,'stateSelected'=>'N/A','citySelected'=>'N/A');

print_r(array($arr1, $arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using the array_merge right way. I just create above array and I got the output like what you expect.

```
$arr1=[];
$arr1[0]=["countrySelected"=>3,"stateSelected"=>NULL,"citySelected"=>NULL];
print_r($arr1);
```

I get array below output

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [countrySelected] => 3
>               [stateSelected] => 
>               [citySelected] => 
>           )
>   )

Then I just create another array like the second array in your question

```
$arr1=[];

$arr1[0]=["countrySelected"=>3,"stateSelected"=>NULL,"citySelected"=>NULL];


print_r($arr1);
```

I get array below output

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [countrySelected] => 4
>               [stateSelected] => 
>               [citySelected] => 
>           )
>   )

and then I just merge the array

`print_r(array_merge($arr1,$arr2));`

and I got the below result

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [countrySelected] => 3
>               [stateSelected] => 
>               [citySelected] => 
>           )
>
> [1] => Array
>           (
>               [countrySelected] => 4
>               [stateSelected] => 
>               [citySelected] => 
>           )
>
> )

Answer (score -1):

you can use two `foreach` loop for your 2 arrays and add them to third array.

```
foreach($arr1 as $item){
  $arr3[]=$item;
}
foreach($arr2 as $item){
  $arr3[]=$item;
}
```